# If formula comparing two columns

Tags: excel-formula

Need a formula that says if the combination of information in Column 3 & 4 in the same row match the combination of Column 1 & 2 in the same row then say YES, otherwise say No.  Column 5 shows what I would like to see.  There is a orange in column 1  that has 2222222 in column 2 so it would show as NO where as there is a Banana in Column I that has 2222222 in column 2.

[image: Example]

```
FIRST SET OF VALUES             SECOND SET OF VALUES                
COLUMN 1    COLUMN 2        COLUMN 3   COLUMN 4 COLUMN 5        
ORANGE          11111111        ORANGE     22222222 NO      
BANANA          22222222        BANANA     22222222 YES     
PEAR            33333333        PEAR       55555555 NO      
PEAR            44444444        WATERMELON 55555555 YES     
WATERMELON  11111111        GRAPES     66666666 YES     
WATERMELON  55555555        PEACH      33333333 YES     
GRAPES          66666666        PLUM       44444444 NO      
GRAPES          77777777        PINEAPPLE  34343434 YES 
GRAPES          22222222                            
PEACH           33333333                        
PLUM            88888888                            
PLUM            77777777                            
PINEAPPLE   99999999                            
PINEAPPLE   12121212                            
PINEAPPLE   34343434                            
PINEAPPLE   56565656
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS():

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(I:I,M3,J:J,N3),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! It worked.  Thank you so much.  Every time I think I get these formula a new situation pops up.